# Setting flags in a coroutine

Tags: python-3.x, coroutine

I'm trying to use [vcxproj-stream-editor](https://github.com/marktsuchida/vcxproj-stream-editor) to edit my .vcxproj files. What I want to do is:

1. Call `check_file` to see if a section exists in the file and set a flag.
2. If the flag isn't set, call `filter_file` to add it.

But how do I set a flag inside the coroutine called by `check_file`? I've tried declaring a global flag:

```
#! python3

import vcxproj

Configuration_debug_x64 = None

@vcxproj.coroutine
def print_project_guid():
    while True:
        action, params = yield
        if action == "start_elem" and params["name"] == "PropertyGroup":
            if "attrs" in params:
                if "Label" in params["attrs"]:
                    if params["attrs"]["Label"] == "Configuration":
                        if "Condition" in params["attrs"]:
                            if params["attrs"]["Condition"] == "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'":
                                Configuration_debug_x64 = True

vcxproj.check_file("My.vcxproj", print_project_guid)

if Configuration_debug_x64:
    print("Configuration_debug_x64")
else:
    print("No Configuration_debug_x64")
```

but that doesn't work, and I can't add a parameter to the function I pass to `check_file`. Is there some obvious method I'm missing?